# Why can't I redirect to home after logging in in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

I'm having trouble with laravel 8, I'm using the default laravel authentication, but it seems that after I log in I can't redirect to the Home page. I just added this to the LoginController `public function username() { return 'username'; }`
Here is my table `protected $table = 'TO_USER_LOGIN';`, I also added the fillables.

my HomeController is fine it just that it won't let me redirect to the Homepage. The `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;` also has a default value `'/home'`

LoginView

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Outer Row -->
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-login-image"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="p-5">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">TRAVEL ORDER SYSTEM</h1>
                            </div>
                            <form method="POST" class="user" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control form-control-user @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autocomplete="off" autofocus>

                                    @error('username')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control form-control-user @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="off">

                                    @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                            </form>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function redirectTo(){
        Redirect::route('home');
    }
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest',['except' => ['logout', 'userLogout']]);
    }
    public function userLogout(){
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any error? or what is the state after you login? you have only said that you can't but WHAT is actually happening.

Comment: @Psycho Yeah I forgot to write it, there wasn't any error , even when I inspect it. After submitting it just redirects me to the login page again.

Comment: may be your login is failing and you haven't show any error message? Please add your login controller to your question

Comment: @Psycho I inspect it, again and again, it gives me the 302 Status code, I am just using the Laravels default authentication. also added the login controller.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem! It was with my table all along, laravel was looking for a column `id` which my table doesn't have instead it has an incremented `UserID` so I changed it to `id` and it worked! There was no error so basically, I tried thinking as much as I could even tried making a new project just to see if I have a problem with my current one.